# Insert new blank row in ms.excel using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel-2007

How can I insert a blank row in Excel using VB.NET?

Comment: Go back over your questions and find the answers that helped you solve your question, click the tick to accept the answer. it helps both you and the persion who answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks roughly like this:

```
Dim range1 As Excel.Range
// set range location eg row 5  "5:5" 
range1.Insert(Excel.xlShiftDown, Excel.xlFormatFromRightOrBelow)
```

Comment: how about delete a row in excel ?

Answer (score -1):

Try This method

```
sheet.Range("A1").EntireRow.Delete();
```